# Printing global variables in body in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, html, global

I'm working with a piece of code I'm designing in my free time, which is a bit unorthodox so bear with me here. The page is set to run a variety of pages based on which "" tag the html is being read from. I was just looking for a way to condense a number of pages into a single one, and this seemed like it might be interesting to mess with. If you guys know of better ways to do that, any information would be appreciated.

So far I'd managed to get everything working until I hit a part where I was trying to obtain a form value, assign it to a global variable, and then use a script to print the global variable in the text. In this case, it is asking the user's name, the goal being to reproduce the name in various places throughout the website for a more user-friendly feel. I figure understanding this will be useful in the future. Eventually I'll want to figure out how to create a database of usernames and passwords and all that good stuff, but for now, I'm just looking for a simple fix. I'm probably missing something elementary. Here's the code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: URL('http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs9/i/2006/033/2/c/Matrix_code_by_phi_AU.jpg');
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MasterCode</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        var name = "";
         //user is "finished typing," collect input
        function doneTyping() {
            name = document.getElementById('nameid').value;
            closeElement('welcomepage');
            closeElement('namepage');
            showElement('homepage');
        }

        function closeElement(myelement) {
            document.getElementById(myelement).style.display = "none";
        }

        function showElement(myelement) {
            document.getElementById(myelement).style.display = 'block';
        }

        function enterWebsite() {
            closeElement('namepage');
            closeElement('homepage');
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            }, {
                title: "Change"
            }, {
                resizable: false
            });
            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                closeElement('welcomepage');
                showElement('namepage');
            })
        }

        function writeName() {
            document.write(name);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="enterWebsite()">
    <div id="welcomepage">
        <button id="opener" style='background: url("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fDgJmT5rzlM/Tq8SpW3ZcbI/AAAAAAAAA1I/l02iiclqKkA/s1600/tracking%2Bclub%2Bmeet%2B%2526%2BMisty%2BAlgonquin%2Bshots%2B106.jpg") no-repeat top left; color: #FFFFFF; height: 685px; width: 1350px; font: 75px helvetica, cursive'>Enter MasterCode</button>
    </div>
    <div id="namepage">
        <form id='name_input'>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <center>
                <input style="background-image:URL('https://waypointprod.blob.core.windows.net/blogfilestore/storage/blogs/headlines/2013/12/5/image.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: ; border: 50px solid black ; height:50px; width:350px; color: #FFFFFF; font: 45px helvetica, cursive;"
                id='nameid' type="text" value="Enter your name.">
                <br/>
                <button id='submit_name' onclick='doneTyping(); return false;'>I Accept The Risks</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="homepage">
        <font size="25" color="white">
    Welcome, <script> writeName(); </script>
    </font>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thoughts?
(Edit: Resolved using localStorage as suggested by tewathia)

Comment: Use `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` to store the user name. Then you can retrieve it whenever you want. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: Note that it won't work in ie7 and below http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage. I say screw IE but if you would like wider support, you could of course use cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: I am with you as well, I appreciate the info though. Thanks Arnar.

Comment: </br> ?? it should be <br> or if you want to be backwards compatible <br/>

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I was making that mistake. The code ran through regardless, so I didn't get any errors. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using any sort of RESTful API or even nodejs.
If you are, something I do to prevent storing this data in cookie or in sessionStorage is that I utilize server-side to store. Then you wouldn't need to add as much logic on client-side. This user data could be

```
{
  "name": "Don Jon",
  "favorite_color": "blue"
}
```

you could even display different parts of the page in blue to be super user friendly